# What Are All Separable Solutions of the Laplace Equation?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, proof-writing

Let us call a separable solution of the Laplace equation $\frac{\partial^2\Phi}{\partial x^2}(x,y)+\frac{\partial^2\Phi}{\partial y^2}(x,y)=0$ as a solution of the form $\Phi(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$ which satisfies this equation. My question is that what are *all* such solutions?

I considered the following theorem which states a necessary condition for such solutions.

> **Theorem**. Suppose that $\Phi:[-a,a]\times[-b,b]\to\mathbb{R}$, $X:[-a,a]\to\mathbb{R}$, $Y:[-b,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ are functions such that $\Phi(x,y)=X(x)Y(y).$ Assume that $X\in C^2[-a,a]$ and $Y\in C^2[-b,b]$ and none of them is the zero function. The following is valid
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{\partial^2\Phi}{\partial x^2}(x,y)+\frac{\partial^2\Phi}{\partial y^2}(x,y)=0\implies
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{d^2X}{dx^2}(x)+\lambda X(x)=0 \\
> \frac{d^2Y}{dy^2}(y)-\lambda Y(y)=0
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}
>   for every $(x,y)$ belonging to $[-a,a]\times[-b,b]$. Also, $\lambda$ is some arbitrary real number.

**Proof**. Noting that $\frac{\partial^2\Phi}{\partial x^2}(x,y)=\frac{d^2X}{dx^2}(x)Y(y)$ and $\frac{\partial^2\Phi}{\partial y^2}(x,y)=X(x)\frac{d^2Y}{dy^2}(y)$ and putting it into the Laplace equation we arrive at
\begin{align*}
\frac{d^2X}{dx^2}(x)Y(y)+X(x)\frac{d^2Y}{dy^2}(y)=0,\tag{1}
\end{align*}
which holds for every $x$ and $y$ belonging to $[-a,a]\times[-b,b]$. Dividing both sides by $X(x)Y(y)$, we conclude that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\frac{d^2X}{dx^2}}{X}(x)+\frac{\frac{d^2Y}{dy^2}}{Y}(y)=0
\end{align*}
should hold for those $(x,y)$ belonging to $[-a,a]\times[-b,b]$ such that $X(x)Y(y)\ne 0$. This leaves no other choice but
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\frac{\frac{d^2X}{dx^2}}{X}(x)=-\lambda \\
\frac{\frac{d^2Y}{dy^2}}{Y}(y)=\lambda.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
for the aforementioned $x$ and $y$. Multiplying by $X(x)Y(y)$ and rearranging the terms give the desired result.

**Questions**

$1$. I was thinking what if $X(x)Y(y)=0$ for some $(x,y)$? For example, take $\lambda=-\omega^2$ and solve the ODEs, then some function like $\Phi(x,y)=\sinh(w x)\sin(w y)$ satisfies the Laplace equation and the ODEs. It also vanishes whenever $x=0$ or $y=0$. However, my proof seems not to be working at such points.

A natural question to be asked is

> Do **all** of the separable solutions $\Phi(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$ of the Laplace equation, should satisfy that pair of ODEs?

I know that the answer is YES, but I don't know how to make an argument about that. Or maybe I am making a stupid mistake around here!?

$2$. Is there any other type of argument which may avoid these things?

Recently, I found that I have asked a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1864126/separation-of-variables-and-linear-pdes), which is slightly different, about an year ago but I did not receive a good answer.

Any hint or help is appreciated. :)

Comment: I think there is an issue with the paragraph beginning with 'I was thinking what if $X(x)Y(y) = 0$?'. $X(x)Y(y) = 0$ implies the product is $0$ **_for all values of $x$ and $y$_**, and not just some particular values like the $\sinh(\omega x) \sin(\omega y)$ example you gave. Hence, $X(x)Y(y) = 0$ implies $u$ is identitically $0$. The ODEs need to solve the Laplace problem on the whole domain, not just some arbitrary points.

Comment: @Mattos I mean it is zero for **some values** as it is clear by my example. :) The point is to show that at those points where the product vanishes, the ODEs *must* be satisfied. The proof just take care  of the points where the product does not vanish.

Answer (score 2):

When you separate variables, you are only constructing **some** special solutions, you are not trying to get **all** solutions. That's why you do not worry too much when assuming that no function vanishes too often.

A posteriori, after you have constructed enough solutions with separate variables, you will see if you can obtain the general (and unique) solution to your original boundary value problem as a superposition of the special solutions you found in the previous step. In the case at hand, it turns out that the special solutions you constructed before suffice (indeed, this is the rediscovery of Fourier series). Therefore, there is no need to worry about the non-vanishing assumptions you made in the previous step.

Comment: (+1), Thanks for the attention. But my concern right now is not about the BVP but just finding *all* of the separable solutions of the form $X(x)Y(y)$ for the Laplace equation. What I got from your answer is that this procedure does not give us *all* of the separable solutions. right? So can you give some example which is separable but does not satisfy those ODES mentioned in the theorem?

Comment: I think that in this case you find all solutions of the form $X(x)Y(y)$. Roughly speaking, I think that even if there are some points $x_0, y_0$ at which $X$ and/or $Y$ vanish, those points are isolated, so the argument can be applied in each subinterval.

Comment: The point is that we know the ODEs are valid also at those points but the proof I have written does not work for such points. Maybe we should go a different route for a nice proof! :)

Comment: The different route is the following: decompose $X$ and $Y$ in eigenfunctions of the operator $-\frac{d^2}{dz^2}$ (with $z=x, y$ respectively).

Comment: I don't know why you insist on that point of view. Let me make a clear mathematical question. What are *all* separable solutions, i.e. those of the form $X(x)Y(y)$, of the Laplace equation? In my opinion, this should not have any business with eigen-functions what so ever as I have not provided any boundary conditions. :)